# Camel Audio Alchemy

Tags: sample

Hello all,

i've recently purchased alchemy. Im blown away by its power and capabilities but I was wondering if anyone on here uses it and can share some of their techniques and work flow and what they use alchemy for?

thanks

Tom

Answer (score 6):

I think Alchemy is best used for:

### granular

Very easy to control in Alchemy and the various algorithms and the parameters offer the ability to tune the best sound quality for the sound you're granulating.

### additive

It's not the best implementation around as it's pretty painful to use/control from scratch, because there's no option to control groups of harmonics, nor is there any kind of "musical guidance" so basically you edit (and ought to know how to edit) every partial by hand. The editor can also be slow/buggy, but it's still nice/useful in e.g. resynthesis.

### resynthesis

which can give you very clear and wide-range real-time pitch and time stretching and gives the ability to tune individual harmonics of the sound in the additive editor that basically allows one to modify/transform the sound without much limitations (although the editor is a bit limiting).

### and subtractive

because the breadth of available filters gives a lot of variation there. As well as the extensive modulation options.

Also,

The ability to use samples and synthesized waveforms (which can also be custom drawn by the user) interchangeably is pretty wicked for all kinds of sounds and especially pads, sequenced stuff and arpeggios. But combining samples and synthesized waveforms really gives a lot of options in tuning any kind of musical or non-musical sound by layering.

The route-anything-anywhere modulation as well as the various modulator options are also powerful and can be used for creating all kinds of movement. The performance controllers including the XY-pads are also nice. The remix pad is a unique feature and can be used for anything where you'd like to sweep through different variations or states (imagine modulating the mix of different ambiences for example).

Minuses:

- No FM synthesis.
- No multiple outputs.
- The additive editor is cumbersome.
- The modulation matrix could be easier to view, it becomes hard to control and recall what modulates what when there are loads of modulations.
- The spectral editor is pretty cumbersome and difficult to use (compared to e.g. Metasynth).

Summary:

Best thought as a supercharged sampler (basically it does more than almost any other sampler on single or few samples). Most suited for musical use (it's an instrument), but the granular capabilities, real-time pitch and time stretching with resynthesis and the modulation options are useful for all sounds (i.e. e.g. working on sound effects). For additive and spectral synthesis there are better tools.